# Getting started with Tradestation webAPI

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, tradestation

I want to build an application that can pull stock data (high, low, volume, etc) from the past ten years in intervals of five minutes using the Tradestation webAPI.  I am looking at: http://tradestation.github.io/webapi-docs/# and I seem to be in way over my head.

Is this a project that someone with little networking knowledge can do in around a month?

Are there any detailed tutorials that explain how to get access tokens and such?

I plan on writing the application in python, but any information that is network-noob friendly would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Using the Tradestation API you can only pull a maximum of 200 days of 5 minute bars.  The API is geared around real time application development rather than downloading historical data.  If you would like to download Tradestation data for use outside of the platform, there is a indicator provided by Ninja Trader that you could take a look at: http://www.ninjatrader.com/support/forum/showthread.php?t=47969